# Are we going to have enough members to take care of every question that needs it?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, edits, quality-improvement

Question base of SO is very quickly growing, we have already over 11 million questions.

I'm not sure, how many *active* users we have who have both the reputation to edit other's questions/answers, and the knowledge to do so - the only experience I have is that my questions are both rarely visited and even more rarely edited and/or improved by others.

Moreover, there are people (including me) who can barely help by giving answers. At least, personally, whenever I check unanswered questions, I feel myself unable (feeling the lack of ability & knowledge) to solve the problem.

Does the user base of SO sufficient to improve **every** question that needs it? Are there any current (Feb 2016) predictions in the matter?

Comment: Well, just do your own bit by downvoting and flagging for closure as much crap as you can. If you happen upon a good question by luck, upvote instead. Doing so will allow more people to find useful questions, and free up more people to answer them.

Comment: Note that there is a bot that cleans up old, negatively scored questions with no answers so at least some of this is automated.

Comment: @BSMP Yes, I was also wondering on bots, but I thought that not every task that can or should be done in this field are automated - and it's a question, for what it can be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure, how many active users we have who have both the reputation to edit other's questions/answers, and the knowledge to do so

Well, editing questions and answers for improvement is considered an important quality keep up mechanism of the site.

> Moreover, there are people (including me) who can barely help by giving answers.

There are loads of (formal) things that can be reasonably improved by a simple edit, ranging from grammatical corrections to fix code formatting issues.

That said, IMHO there are many (enough) users that can contribute and are willing at that level.

Comment: I agree that there is a lot of work in the area of spelling and grammar corrections, but I have found there is a VERY strong contingent of SO editors who reject "minor edits" like these out of hand.  I have had some of my spelling/grammar edits rejected by people who reject 90%+ of the edits they review, and they are proud of this fact.  Apparently we don't want to reward people with reputation points for such pedestrian fare.  So as long as people feel this way, SO will continue to be riddled with typos and grammatical errors.